# Can the HTML 'class' element attribute contain line breaks?

Tags: css, html

Can the 'class' attribute of HTML5 elements contain line breaks? Is it allowable in the specs and do browsers support it?

I ask because I have some code that dynamically inserts various classes into the element and this has created one very long line that is hard to manage. Normally I would build the class value using a variable but the CMS I'm using requires the template conditional tags to be positioned inline with the HTML. I can't use variables or PHP.

What I found in my research is that some HTML tag attributes need to be a single line, but I haven't been able to discover if the class attribute is one of those.

Does anyone know something about this?

Comment: Please post code , its always better to show wat you are working on with snippets and test pages

Comment: Which attributes "attributes need to be a single line"?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Per the [HTML 4 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/index/attributes.html), the `class` attribute is [`CDATA`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-cdata):

> User agents should interpret attribute values as follows:
>
> o Replace character entities with characters
>
> o Ignore line feeds
>
> o Replace each carriage return or tab with a single space.

so you're in good shape there.

The [HTML5 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#classes) describes a class as a [set of space separated tokens](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#set-of-space-separated-tokens), where a 'space' includes newlines.

So you should be good there, too.

Comment: Thanks Dancrumb. So, do you think that most browsers will support this fine?

Comment: they ought to... the HTML4 spec is from 1999

Comment: Re: browser compatibility - as it happens, I recently came across a case at work where using newlines in class attributes was preventing jQuery from correctly selecting using class-based CSS selectors in IE 8 - as if IE 8 or jQuery-in-IE-8 didn't see the newline as whitespace, but as part of a class name. Replacing newlines with spaces solved the problem. Frustratingly, though, while I can reproduce this with my particular code from work (checking out before and after the replacement of newlines), in simpler test cases it seems like IE 8 handles this fine, and I can't share my code from work.

Comment: I wish I could be more helpful, but I've tried dragging more and more details across from my work code to my test case to try and reproduce the issue and have not succeeded. All I can really tell you is that there's *something* fishy about IE 8's support of newlines in class attributes.

Comment: Is it, perhaps, a jQuery issue? What does native JS report as the class value? Perhaps jQuery is parsing it incorrectly.

Comment: The world will be a better place when big businesses ditch XP / IE 8 :)

Comment: @MarkAmery It would have been great to know if the page was in quirks mode. Just dropping, in case you could still investigate this.

Comment: I break my class into two-line but it's the effect on the browser while inspecting

Answer (score 9):

> Can the `[class]` attribute of HTML5 elements contain line breaks?

Yes. [The HTML5 spec says](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/single-page.html#classes):

> The attribute, if specified, must have a value that is a [set of space-separated tokens](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/single-page.html#set-of-space-separated-tokens) representing the various classes that the element belongs to.

The link proceeds to say:

> A **set of space-separated tokens** is a string containing zero or more words (known as tokens) separated by one or more [space characters](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/single-page.html#space-character), where words consist of any string of one or more characters, none of which are [space characters](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/single-page.html#space-character).

And space characters include:

- space (`' '`)
- tab (`\t`)
- line feed (`\n`)
- form feed (`\f`)
- carriage return (`\r`)

> The **space characters**, for the purposes of this specification, are U+0020 SPACE, "tab" (U+0009), "LF" (U+000A), "FF" (U+000C), and "CR" (U+000D).

Newlines as you would add to UTF-8 documents are:

- line feeds (`\n`)
- carriage returns (`\r`)
- a carriage return followed immediately by a line feed (`\r\n`)