# Scrape data from e-commerce site python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I manage to scrape data from ebay and I am trying to do the same from another site but the structure of html code is slightly different and due to that I am not able to scrape the data.
I am trying with the following code

```py
k = requests.get('https://www.skroutz.gr/plus-deals').text
soup=BeautifulSoup(k,'html.parser')
productlist = soup.find_all("li",{"class":"cf card\nadd-to-cart-cta"})
print(productlist)
```

I think the problem as you can see is because with in the class there is a line break.

[image]

Also I tried to scrape the title from the same page but I was not able as well.

[image]

This is the link : skroutz.gr/plus-deals

Thank you

Comment: The HTML classes when being rendered do not have line breaks. You can read more here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14928536/can-the-html-class-element-attribute-contain-line-breaks.  Remove '\n' from the class that's not there, it's just a space, not line change. It looks like a line because it's too big to display in single line

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to specify all the classes of the element, you can just simply pick them up specifying one class like `cf`, try this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

html = requests.get('https://www.skroutz.gr/plus-deals').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')

products_list = soup.find_all("li",{"class":"cf"})
for product in products_list:
    print(product)
```